# How to detect if a Chrome OS device model supports Android programatically?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, chromium-os

I have a Chrome OS packaged app published with some installations. Given that Chrome OS now supports Android apps, I need some way to detect how many of my existing customers are using a [device model that supports Android](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps).

I browsed through the APIs and found `chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo` but it doesn't respond with the device model. I'm wondering if there's a more reliable way to detect it.

Comment: Even if their chromebook supports android apps, the user may have it disabled in the settings, or it could be disabled by enterprise policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/api/chromeos_info_private.json#39) that does exactly what I want. Unfortunately it is private.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API that exposes the device (board) name to JS code.  There are some private/internal APIs, but people don't get access to those for normal apps published in the Chrome Web Store (CWS).

You could try and fingerprint the device by gathering various source details (such as [display metrics](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display) and built in [USB devices](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb)), but that'll require quite a bit of effort, and probably still not catch them all :(.